# Excel - Formula in shape recalculates on open

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, shapes

I have a shape in Excel which is assigned to macro which resets filters. When filters are set, there's a formula in the shape which makes it say: "Filter set". The formula goes like "=G1", not more. G1 is the cell where it gets evaluated whether a filter is set or not and outputs the text which will be shown in the shape.

Here's the problem: every time I open the workbook, even if no change has been made in the document, upon closing Excel asks if I want the document to be saved. The problem is the shape recalculating the value in the cell, if I delete these shapes this problem won't happen. 
I already tried making a macro

```
Sub Workbook_Open()  
    ThisWorkbook.Save 
End Sub
```

and although this macro really runs on startup (tested it with a msgbox), it doesn't solve the problem. I've also inserted a waitloop in here (dirty hack, I know) but I also didn't really got it to work. Any other ideas of what I could try?

Comment: What is the problem? It sounds like this is normal. What would you prefer?

Comment: The problem is that, if I open the workbook and make no change in the document, when I close it it asks if I want to save it. Which shouldn't happen because I didn't make any change. This is also written in the question

Comment: But you also wrote that your formulas change the text every time a calculation event occurs. You don't want to stop the calculation. You also don't really want to suppress that message. So your options are to accept this as the normal behavior or change what you are doing with that shape. For example, if you stopped using G1 and used a VBA variable to hold the text for the shape.

Comment: True, I don't want the formula to stop recalculating. Except when I open the document, there is no change happening, it might just be open to view it. So I wouldn't like the formula "=G1" in the shape to do any recalculation in that case. I wonder why running this macro which is ran when the workbook is opened runs the .save but the prompt for saving the file still appears after. If I save the file manually after opening, the prompt doesn't appear. 
Anyway, it all seems pretty weird Excel behaviour which I'm getting used to and I think I'll just have to live with some inconveniences. Thanks!